# How to get artifacts from tfs build server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I use TFS 2017(15.117) on premise with a build & release def.
My build pushes the build result (zip package) to the artifactstaging directory on the build server.

In my release def I have 2 tasks (Manage IIS & Deploy IIS) and I want to make use of the artifactstaging directory on the build server to reference the zip pacakge but I don't know how to do this using the variables...

How can this be done using the same agent pool and queue that is also used by the build definition ?

Comment: See if this [helps](https://sameersarena.blogspot.com/2017/12/automated-builds-and-deployments-using_15.html)

Comment: Seems you are getting the similar error as this one https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4152 ?

Comment: The issue is that the WinRM Deploy IIS App task in TFS gives a hint that the .zip web deploy package file should be at a file share on the target machine or on a UNC path. Because the artifact download is at the build server, the path is not available for the app server... I am trying to copy the web deploy package as a file copy task to a share on the app server

Comment: @PatrickPeters If so, you could try to use [Deploy: Windows Machine File Copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) which could copy the  .zip pacakge  in drop folders of build server to app server. About the variable take a look at: [Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#buildartifactstagingdirectory) The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. `: c:\agent\_work\1\a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `Publish Artifact` task. Look at one of the built-in templates for examples.

Using that task automatically pushes the specified binaries to the location you specify (either a UNC share, or within the TFS instance itself). It then creates an Artifact link against the build result, so when you queue a release of the build, the release can automatically retrieve the artifacts associated with the build.

Comment: The agent on the build server is used to download the artifacts, but the release fails because I get the error 'Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one or more machines failed. System.Exception: [...path\..zip] doesn't exists. But when I go the build server and paste that path in Windows Explorer I get the contents of the zip file, so the file does exists... What could be wrong then ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use extra variables in release to fetch build artifacts. In your Release definition setting, there is a part of [Artifact sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/artifacts?view=vsts#sources). TFS will auto download them to the agent.

You can link a release definition to **any of the build definitions** in your Team Foundation Server project collection.

[image]

> By default, a release created from the release definition **will use
>   the latest version of the artifacts.**
>
> At the time of linking an artifact source to a release definition, you
>   can change this behavior by selecting one of the options to use the
>   latest build from a specific branch by specifying the tags, a specific
>   version, or allow the user to specify the version when the release is
>   created from the definition.

***Note:*** You must include a [Publish Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts) task step in your build definition.

More details, suggest you first go through the official tutorial in MSDN: [Artifacts in Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/artifacts?view=vsts)

Comment: Linking artifacts only downloads during a release to the given agent. I reuse the same agent as the build does, so all artifacts are downloaded to the build server... The IIS Deploy tasks demands the web deploy package to be downloaded to a share or local path (= build server this case).